# The method toSet() was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: toSet()

Tags: list, flutter, exception, null

Here in this code I'm getting an exception :

Exception caught by widgets library
The method 'toSet' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toSet()

The code is here :

```
getCommonCats(position) {
 final List lists = [_campList[position].categories, catName];

final commonCats = lists.fold<Set>(
    
        lists.first.toSet(), (a, b) => a.intersection(b.toSet())

    );
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve here.. is `catName` an array or an object you want to append to `lists`?

Comment: catName is the List

Comment: So you want to combine `_campList[position].categories` and `catName` then store the common categories in the variable `commonCats`?

Comment: yes. I just want to know that is there any substitute of toSet() method, any custom code to set the values in the list.